# Gitlab - Can't add ssh key

Tags: ssh, gitlab, archlinux

I have installed gitlab using AUR on my archlinux server.
Everything is now working well, except that I can not add ssh keys.

I get the error `Fingerprint cannot be generated`.
In the log I got only

```
Started GET "/profile/keys/new" for my.ip.on.arch at 2015-03-28 13:13:52 +0100
Processing by Profiles::KeysController#new as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 110.9ms | ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)
Started POST "/profile/keys" for 92.157.142.177 at 2015-03-28 13:13:58 +0100
Processing by Profiles::KeysController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WX7VMJy1Ftk9xUWc7OL5zT5IrmqBbU22HJJVpFh6IBY=", "key"=>{"title"=>"my@email", "key"=>"ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDETfMjbXE8lZga4YWtO82dEH6AJYVOIt3L8emTEynpZed0WvDeky2tZT8VhwKSTjJ90e14usUxArOMaeWyQqdAhS3lym5DZlEN/vXfsUCnCuX3dpJfXjAefR9z9/BQdhwxwcf9cdWLGiixZ8U91Hs4k2RXPT4Q746jZCE/OyWLbO1mibaQD1mMkMf8d3jPJ9+jXAt2c2U83DPEaZ4AIm+M0Jv3X6MIQreeHgFRIg2lMEs16Mw/Y638ZK3WzX/qk1Z9RngKIkIh4afc9TZm2bt0jEUxXMly3cBQ03wTtmlf1lEkVNYjFP19fVfWei2JFdnEFLlsCuNpyeenwCTargwV my@email"}}
Completed 200 OK in 175ms (Views: 95.2ms | ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)
```

I've just for test switch chmod 777 everywhere I thought (`/tmp`, `/var/lib/gitlab/.ssh`), and it is still failing.

I've read a lot of things about such issues on CentOS with SELinux, but I'm not using SELinux...

If someone has an idea, that will be great!
Thank you a lot,

Comment: Do NOT use mode 777 for ssh key/config files. They'll be rejected for being insecure.

Comment: True, I was not testing to use them, but to add in the file. Obviously now, I reverted to 750.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to a new openSSH version. A fix has been proposed here : 
https://github.com/sstanovnik/gitlabhq/blob/openssh_fix/app/models/key.rb

Issue is tracked here : https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/9008

Comment: Good catch. +1. I have delete my answer (just noise here)